# Exporting Text is showing a Render Error in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, packaging

I have made a [components library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) for ReactNative using react-native-builder-bob  for packaging. With some components like Button, Image, etc is working great, but when I try to import a Text component is failing and showing this error:

> View config getter callback for component 'RCTTEXT' must be a function
> (receive undefined)

If in the project where I import this component do some change, the view is refreshed and the error dissapears, but every time I run the project for first time this error is shown.

Here is the imported component:

```
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export const MyText = ({...props}) => <Text {...props} />;
```

And after, this is the way I import this component in another app:

```
import { MyText } from 'my-library'

export const Example = () => {
   return <MyText>Hello</MyText>
}
```

I was searching for the error of 'View config getter....' and the only I found is, provocated by importing error, but only happens with this component.

What thing could be provocating this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using your custom text component like this.

```
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export const MyText = ({children, ...props}) => <Text {...props}>{children}</Text>;
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: No, keep failing.  I dont know only fail with Text from react-native.

Comment: Can you show me what is the error.

Comment: If I export a Text from my  React Native component library and I import in another app, it is show the error: 'view config getter callback for component 'RCTText' must be a function(received `undefined`). Although, if I use this component in a screen which is not the main screen, it is working. Maybe could be something related with the load of the app?

Comment: Did you try creating the same component in your project and export the `MyText` from that to see if this error is coming or not?

Comment: Yes, and works perfectly. Something is happening when I import a component with Text inside. Even is failing when only do the import, without using it. But, the most strange is, because is not failing when I refresh the app? only happen at the beggining

Comment: Can you do change like this in your component render method
`return <> {children ? <Text {...props}>{children}</Text> : null} </>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245163/discussion-between-agustin-herrera-and-akash-chavda).

Answer (score 0):

well....finally I found the error. Everything is all great from my library of components, but, apparently, in my component library I have the react-native version 0.68.0 and, in the app where I was importing this components I had a lower version (0.67.3). If I use the same version, it is working!